# How to tell the headhunter that I need more time for relocating to an other country (contractor offer)?

Tags: recruitment, relocation

I got a contractor job offer in an other country which I want to take but my problem is that they want me to start pretty soon.

My notice period is one month and I should start at my new place 1 week after it ends.

My problem is that I won't really be able to travel to that country during my notice period to look for apartments, and I also have a holiday already booked that starts one week after I should start at my new place.

The headhunter pushes me, he says it is pretty urgent for them, it is also okay for them if I go on vacation only after 1 week of work etc..
But during the interview process they only asked my notice period, they didn't say that it is very urgent nor asked about my already booked vacations, and they must have been aware that I have to move to a country 2000 miles away from mine.

I'm afraid if I hold on to starting only after my vacation I might lose the offer.

EDIT: This would be a contractor position, so I won't get any money for relocation or anything.

Comment: Would looking for an apartment remotely be a possibility? Then if you have an apartment, you could simply go there and buy the minimum necessities until you can get your things from home at a later date?

Comment: Have you agreed the start date yet? If not, it's typically not a big deal to negotiate what is convenient for you - especially if you have valid reasons.

Comment: Off topic .. but for  contract job you should have built relocation and accommodation expenses into to the rate you are being paid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking at the problem the wrong way.

If your new employer is desperate enough to want you to start for a week before your previously scheduled vacation instead of after it; you're right that trying to get them to delay your start date would burn a lot of good will.  Instead, you should ask for (additional?) relocation assistance funds to cover a hotel for your first week on the job so you can look for a place to live long term at the same time you're starting to work.

Comment: I will work for them as a contractor, the company won't pay anything for relocation.

Comment: So you need to relocate for a contractor job? This is an important information and should be written.

Comment: @Cris Yes, that is right

Answer (score 2):

Talk with them and find a compromise. State clearly that you won't be able to relocate with so little time. Ask them if they would:

a. Let you work remotely with urgent issues while you relocate

b. Grant you funds to relocate and help with paperwork

If they are asking you to work ASAP for them, this means they are in a hurry and you are good enough for them. If you can leverage the urgency that would be strategic. If they really need you fast, they will spend a few bucks for make it happen, also they don't want to burn bridges by pushing hard for you to move, if they do, maybe it's not worth the effort.